# How to generate conditions within constraints in Z3py

Tags: z3, z3py

Let us assume there are 5-time slots and at each time slot, I have 4 options to choose from, each with a known reward, for eg. `rewards = [5, 2, 1, -3]`. At every time step, at least 1 of the four options must be selected, with a condition that, if option 3 (with reward -3) is chosen at a time t, then for the *remaining* time steps, none of the options should be selected. As an example, considering the options are indexed from 0, both [2, 1, 1, 0, 3] and [2, 1, 1, 3, 99] are valid solutions with the second solution having option 3 selected in the 3rd time step and 99 is some random value representing no option was chosen.

The Z3py code I tried is here:

```
T = 6 #Total time slots
s = Solver()

pick = [[Bool('t%d_ch%d' %(j, i)) for i in range(4)] for j in range(T)]

# Rewards of each option
Rewards = [5, 2, 1, -3]

# Select at most one of the 4 options as True
for i in range(T):
    s.add(Or(Not(Or(pick[i][0], pick[i][1], pick[i][2], pick[i][3])),
          And(Xor(pick[i][0],pick[i][1]), Not(Or(pick[i][2], pick[i][3]))),
            And(Xor(pick[i][2],pick[i][3]), Not(Or(pick[i][0], pick[i][1])))))

# If option 3 is picked, then none of the 4 options should be selected for the future time slots
# else, exactly one should be selected.
for i in range(len(pick)-1):
    for j in range(4):
        
        s.add(If(And(j==3,pick[i][j]), 
                 
                 Not(Or(pick[i+1][0], pick[i+1][1], pick[i+1][2], pick[i+1][3])),
                 
                 Or(And(Xor(pick[i+1][0],pick[i+1][1]), Not(Or(pick[i+1][2], pick[i+1][3]))),
                    And(Xor(pick[i+1][2],pick[i+1][3]), Not(Or(pick[i+1][0], pick[i+1][1]))))))

if s.check()==False:
    print("unsat")
    
m=s.model()
print(m)
```

With this implementation, I am not getting solutions such as [2, 1, 1, 3, 99]. All of them either do not have option 3 or have it in the last time slot.

I know there is an error inside the If part but I'm unable to figure it out. Is there a better way to achieve such solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to decipher what you're trying to do. From a basic reading of your description, I think this might be an instance of the XY problem. See https://xyproblem.info/ for details on that, and try to cast your question in terms of what your original goal is; instead of a particular solution, you're trying to implement. (It seems to me that the solution you came up with is unnecessarily complicated.)

Having said that, you can solve your problem as stated if you get rid of the `99` requirement and simply indicate `-3` as the terminator. Once you pick `-3`, then all the following picks should be `-3`. This can be coded as follows:

```py
from z3 import *

T = 6
s = Solver()

Rewards = [5, 2, 1, -3]
picks = [Int('pick_%d' % i) for i in range(T)]

def pickReward(p):
    return Or([p == r for r in Rewards])

for i in range(T):
    if i == 0:
        s.add(pickReward(picks[i]))
    else:
        s.add(If(picks[i-1] == -3, picks[i] == -3, pickReward(picks[i])))

while s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    picked = []
    for i in picks:
        picked += [m[i]]

    print(picked)
    s.add(Or([p != v for p, v in zip(picks, picked)]))
```

When run, this prints:

```
[5, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3]
[1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1]
[1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1]
[2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1]
[2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1]
[2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1]
[1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 1]
[2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2]
[2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2]
[2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
[2, 5, 5, 5, 5, -3]
[2, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5]
...
```

I interrupted the above as it keeps enumerating all the possible picks. There are a total of 1093 of them in this particular case.

(You can get different answers depending on your version of z3.)

Hope this gets you started. Stating what your original goal is directly is usually much more helpful, should you have further questions.